# MUI list item secondary action button also affects entire list item onClick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a list item:

```
      <ListItem
        button
        secondaryAction={
          <IconButton
            edge='end'
            aria-label='more'
            onClick={() => console.log('hello')}
          >
            <MoreHorizIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <ListItemIcon>
          {!isFolderOpen ? (
            <FolderIcon sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main }} />
          ) : (
            <FolderOpenIcon
              sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main }}
            />
          )}
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={name && name} />
      </ListItem>
```

The problem is when clicking the `IconButton` in the `secondaryAction`, it also triggers the `onClick` in the `<ListItem>` itself:

Clicking this:

```
onClick={() => console.log('hello')}
```

Also triggers this:

```
onClick={handleClick}
```

I want the behavior to be separate. Clicking one should not trigger the other.

I tried adding a `<ListItemButton>` as shown in the docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/#main-content

Although it works to separate the onClick, it messes up the style like this:
[image]

It's as if there are two separate sections now on hover.

Here is the code that corresponds to the picture above:

```
      <ListItem
        // button
        secondaryAction={
          <IconButton
            edge='end'
            aria-label='more'
            onClick={() => console.log('hello')}
          >
            <MoreHorizIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        // onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
          <ListItemIcon>
            {!isFolderOpen ? (
              <FolderIcon sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main }} />
            ) : (
              <FolderOpenIcon
                sx={{ color: theme => theme.palette.primary.main }}
              />
            )}
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={name && name} />
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: You need to add `disablePadding` to the `ListItem` in your second approach in order to fix the styles.

Comment: Thank you!!!! You saved me from hours of frustration! Appreciate that!